# Application of the transversality theorem

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, transversality

I am trying to do this question in Bredon's *Topology and geometry* about using the transversality theorem to show that the intersection of two manifolds is a manifold.

Now it goes as follows:

Let $f(x,y,z)=(2-(x^2+y^2)^{1/2})+z^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^3 - (0,0,z)$. Then one can show that $M=f^{-1}(1)$ is a manifold.

Now let $N = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2=4 \}$. I need to show that $M \cap N$ is a manifolds by using the transversality theorem, but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

I thought about finding the tanget planes to each to these manifolds and then showing that there a points in one of them that aren't in the other, but I dont know if this will work. So I was wondering if I could get some hints on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't fit my response in the character limit of the comment box.

No, your first function needs to be the function $f$ you started with :) You're correct that I was guiding you just to use the regular value set-up. Of course, this is a special case of the transversality theorem. If you try to study the function $h(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2$ on $M$, you end up with a messy local-coordinates computation, so I always discourage my students from trying to show "directly" that the function $h\colon M\to\mathbb R$ has $4$ as a regular value. You could try to see that the inclusion map $\iota\colon M\to\mathbb R^3$ is transverse to the cylinder $N$: As you surmised, you just need to see that at any point $P\in M\cap N$, $T_PM+T_PN = \mathbb R^3$. The way I was leading you is doing this geometrically, by showing that $\nabla f(P)$ (which is the normal vector to $M$) and $\nabla h(P)$ (which is the normal vector to $N$) are linearly independent at every $P\in M\cap N$.

Comment: Thank you :) I see what you mean, but in the last bit when you say doing this geometrically, are you saying that by using the regular value set-up, what I'm in fact doing is showing that the normal vectors to each manifold are lin indep?

Comment: and in any case, can this be used to show that $M$ is transversal to $N$?

Comment: Yes and yes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try writing down a function $g\colon\mathbb R^3-\{z\text{-axis}\}\to \mathbb R^2$ so that, for example, $g^{-1}(1,4) = M\cap N$ and $(1,4)$ is a regular value of $g$.

Comment: OK so I'm guessing $g(x,y,z)=(z^2,x^2+y^2)$? and if so I think i can prove (1,4) is a regular value. But where does the transversality theorem come in? Because it seems to me that having this $g$ is enough to prove its a manifolds, by using the regular level set theorem? or am I missing something?